# Query Multiple in Same Field Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
functionalities.filter(acl_controller='Employee')
```

I want to query functionalities model where acl_controller='Employee' and acl_controller='Manager' and acl_controller='Admin'. I know i can use multiple filters -

```
functionalities.filter(acl_controller='Employee').filter(acl_controller='Manager').filter(acl_controller='Admin')
```

But i want to know is there any better approach to filter out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Q` node. See [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

AND filtering

```
functionalities.filter(
    Q(acl_controller='Employee') &
    Q(acl_controller='Manager') &
    Q(acl_controller='Admin')
)
```

OR filtering

```
functionalities.filter(
    Q(acl_controller='Employee') |
    Q(acl_controller='Manager') |
    Q(acl_controller='Admin')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
functionalities.filter(acl_controller__in=['Employee', 'Manager', 'Admin'])
```